# Batch file to login to Origin

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file that will, when executed, log in into Origin with specific account details. I have no problem with the details being stored in the batch file itself, I just want it to log in when executed.

Context: Working at an Online Gaming Cafe and we would like our computers to auto log into Origin and then launch a game (launching the game after log in is the easy part for me) when someone starts the game they want. Our program auto kills all processes when the customer runs out of time, so we want Origin to auto log in whenever they launch a game.

Extra Info: Most I could find is the following thread: http://forum.smartlaunch.net/Topic26146-18-1.aspx

It does have a batch file, however it seems a little complex and uses another software (SmartLaunch) that we don't use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Novus

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF

SET OriginLogin=
SET OriginPassword=
REM Sets the login and password associated with the specific computer


"E:\Origin\Origin.exe" -login %OriginLogin% %OriginPassword% 
REM Launches Origin from the directory it is installed to (Default: E:\Origin

\Origin.exe)

SET OriginLogin=""
SET OriginPassword=""
REM After Origin is launched the login and password are cleared
```

The problem I believe is that the password must contain a cap. which batch file does not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if Origin has this implemented but there's a feature from Gmail (not sure if it's part of the API) that's commonly used in Rainmeter skins. The request `https://#Username#:#Password#@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom` is sent to the browser, logging the user in. If origin has this available, an auto-login can be accomplished as follows

```
@echo off
set /p user="Username:"
set /p pass="Password:"
start "https://%user%:%pass%/connect.origin.com/ca/login"
exit
```

That would send the given username and password, with that URL, to the user's default browser and log them in (if that happens to be the right request, that is.)

Hope I helped!

Comment: I'm looking to do the log in via the Origin program. I did attempt your solution but to no avail. Your exact script just opens a CMD window that displays "Username:[username I entered]" and nothing else. Thanks for the attempt though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks Origin accept login by command line, I tried using it, -login parameter is the way STEAM does, but in origin seems not to work.

By the way, seting the pass in a BATCH or system variable is the worst that you can do.

There is a lan-game-center software that host all users and password in the administration server, and the client PCs don't store anything, the software runs and sent remotely the user/pass for STEAM, it is way more secure.

But in origin seems don't has support for command line account information.